# WiFi gets disconnected every few minutes and speed is also very low when it is connected

Tags: networking, 20.04, hp, intel, iwlwifi

I have a HP Probook G1 650 with WiFi card of Intel dual band wireless N7260.

My WiFi gets disconnected now and then randomly, first it was occasionally, but now every 5 minutes it gets disconnected
running:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

And its output is:

```
[    5.969398] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.028385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    6.046892] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 7c:5c:f8:56:9f:23
[    6.248506] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.397120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   61.084592] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
```

Please help me I tried many solutions such as ARPing , IPv6 disabling, and updating kernel versions, so please suggest me a solution for this
problem.

The command

```
sudo iwlist wl01 scan
```

produces this output:

```
wl01      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

It is showing this for `iwlist wl01 scan` and for `iwconfig`

This is the rest of the output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SSP"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: A8:02:DB:71:28:DC   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:66   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Remember I said *"NOT into the comments please"*? Please redo, and delete your last two comments. And try this command instead of the first one... `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your router not to disconnect when idle . I had the same problem with Linux Mint 18 on a HP 650 an that worked